# Computing series exactly

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Using the formula $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {x^n} = \frac{1}{1-x}$
take the derivative of both sides with respect to the variable x to find a new formula for another series. Use this formula to compute exactly the series:

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{n}{3^n} = \frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{9} + \frac{3}{27} + \frac{4}{81}$

What is this question asking me to do? I don't know of a way to take the derivative of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} {x^n}$, but that is probably just my lack of experience. I am sorry for the lack of attempt to answer this question, I am completely lost.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$. Can you differentiate $1$? Can you differentiate $x$? Can you differentiate $x^2$?  Can you differentiate $x^3,\ldots$? Can you add up the results?

Answer (score 1):

Note that term by term differentiation followed by multiplication by $x$ gives us that
$$
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=xD\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n} \quad (|x|<1).
$$